# What is Lando Calrissian wearing on his Wrist?

Tags: star-wars, technology, return-of-the-jedi, the-empire-strikes-back

Again, when I visited the [Star-Wars exposition](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/star-wars-identities-the-exhibition/) this summer, I took a photo of Lando Calrissian's costume.

[image: Lando's costume]

I noticed the *nice* wrist device and made a close up of it :

[image: Close-up image]

Unitl now, I thought it was the [Wrist link](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wrist_link) he used to call [Lobot](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lobot), but I just watched the scene and noticed it's not the same device :

[image: Lando's Wrist link]

What exactly is this wrist device on the costume?

Comment: The first photo is Lando's general costume in Return of the Jedi. The blue costume with the wrist link is from Empire Strike Back.

Comment: It's just another comm link of different design,

Comment: Are you guys sure it's not just the Star Wars equivalent of 'Gangsta Bling'? Lando was after all a bit of a bad boy in his past...

Comment: It's a FitBit. Cheap Chinese knockoff of one, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Star Wars: The Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Dictionary) factbook describes it as a ***"Wrist Comlink"***. There's no specific indication why he changed from his [old model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/477XL.png) to this newer one.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As @spicey noted in the comment, it's still a wrist link, just a different model.

As noted in the article you linked to, there were many different wrist links. The one in the picture may have been "rebel leader" model (Bail Organa had a wrist link as well), or simply an updated <strike>iPhone</strike> device. Think of it as TGFFA smartphone.

Comment: In addition, every single detailed review of "General Lando Calrissian" Hasbro figure from Vintage Collection also mentions the wrist communicator/link. Hard to say how canonical that is.